# H subgroup of G with index 2, prove that their centralizers are subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I am struggling with a proof and would like to ask for help. I am required to prove the following: given G is a finite group with a subgroup H of index 2, prove the centralizer of H is a subgroup of the centralizer of G.

My proof is as follows:

[image]

Could someone please verify my proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not see any relation with index of $H$ in $G$. It is always true that $C_H(x)=H\cap C_G(x)$. ?? did you mean some think else ?

Comment: @mesel I think I am trying to prove the intersection you stated, because it is stated in the general question I am working with

Comment: You may see this by only properties of sets. If you write $H\cap C_G(x)$ you will see that you are writing the definition of $C_H(x)$.